# Discord.js Get Number From Message Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

today i was trying to make a bot and i want to get a number from the user message. This was my attempt

```js
Client.on ("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (Config.prefix + 'resetHWID')){
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#6f0bd4')
            .setTitle('Success!')
            .setDescription('Successfully reset HWID for user ' + (message.content - message.content.startsWith (Config.prefix + 'resetHWID')))
        message.channel.send(Embed);
    }
});
```

This was the message that i sent:
flop.resetHWID 5

This is what the bot sent back:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTf6o.png)

The expected output is: 'Successfully reset HWID for user 5

Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

While you could use regex, what I think you're looking for is substring. You want to find the message content after the command name

This should help you achieve that:

```js
Client.on ("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (Config.prefix + 'resetHWID ')){
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#6f0bd4')
            .setTitle('Success!')
            .setDescription('Successfully reset HWID for user ' + message.content.substring((Config.prefix + 'resetHWID ').length));
        message.channel.send(Embed);
    }
});
```